# Start up application automatically after device boot in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, boot, autorun

I want to automatically run my BlackBerry application right after the BlackBerry physical device boot up. I have checked the ***Auto-run on startup*** option in BlackBerry Application Descriptor. Still it does not start-up after the device boot complete.

Is that the correct way of doing it or do I have to `implements SystemListener` in my main class .

Comment: Who do you know that it doesn't start? Is it foreground application? Usually autostart apps require to wait until system is fully up loaded before proceed other actions

Comment: Yes, it is a foreground application with UI.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the `main` method , debug and check if the debugger stops there.

Comment: When I run the app, it stops there. But when I reboot the device how can I track it?

Comment: Put some logs to the constructor. Start sim and check logs